# To convert Datatype "WORD" into char*

Tags: c

I have to convert word datatype into char* to pass in a function.
Could anyone show me how to do it. IT should be in C and not C++.

Also I need to pass into function something like 
2000-3000-2
where 2000 = word datatype 
 3000 = word datatype 
2 = word 
and "-"
while function takes char* as an argument.

so basically i need to convert above combination of word datatype into char*.

Any help or criticism will be helpful

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want to do. An example?

Comment: Do you need a string representation of the integer in the WORD, or is this one of those weird Win32 API hacks where you need to pass in an integer value as an argument that's of a pointer type?

Comment: i need to extract values from structure and values are in WORD datatype. ihave done done now i need to take all these there values followed by hypen as shown in my question and convert into char*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `sprintf()`, perhaps something like this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%.4d-%.4d-%d", w1, w2, w3);
```

where `w1`, `w2` and `w3` are integer variables holding values 2000, 3000 and 2 in your example.

Comment: seem right solution to me.. I will update tomrorow to know whether it worked or not.Thanks

Comment: @samprat, `sprintf` doesn't guard against buffer overflows. Use `snprintf` instead of available.

Comment: @ikegami It's pretty easy to avoid a buffer overflow with integer variables and `sprintf`.

Comment: those values like 200 etc are of datatype WORD and how would I put hypen

Comment: The hyphen is in the format string, the second parameter to `sprintf()`. `%.4d` means "format an integer with a minimum of 4 digits. It's exactly the same as `printf()` which I am assuming you have used.

Comment: @David, sorry my mistake, I havnt catch it better. Thanks for all the help .